# Microsoft SQL Server Erro 10060

Tags: sql

Recentemente formatei meu computador e reinstalei os aplicativos. Entre eles o SQL Server 2014.
O problema é que eu não consigo conectar no servidor do provedor! 
Desinstalei a versão 2014 e instalei a 2012 e o problema persiste.
Somente na minha máquina acontece isso.
Não é problema na rede pois eu consigo conectar no SQL do meu servidor interno.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: você chegou a ver este link? http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb326282.aspx é necessário desabilitar as portas pro SQL, já fez isso?

Comment: Só pra eu entender: você quer conectar nesse servidor, que é a sua máquina, através de outra máquina. É isso?

Comment: mais uma coisa, como diz no próprio link... é necessário configurar o servidor para aceitar conexões remotas

Comment: Então, eu quero conectar no servidor que fica localizado no provedor.
Eu tinha visto esse link, mas as soluções apresentadas não resolvem meu problema, porque no provedor está habilitado para aceitar conexão remota, pois eu consigo conectar de qualquer outra máquina, menos desta.

Comment: Bem, confirme se as configurações de conexão estejam corretas no SSMS

Comment: Os dados de conexão estão corretos. Conferi conectando a partir de outra máquina. Digitei e redigitei 700x pra ver se não tinha erro... :(

Comment: Pergunta idiota, habilitou os protocolos do SQL no Configuration Manager?

Comment: Os protocolos na estação estão habilitados e aparentemente no servidor também, pois se eu consigo acessar de outras estações...

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o site da [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb326282.aspx)

> Ocorreu um erro ao estabelecer uma conexão com o servidor. Ao conectar-se ao SQL Server, essa falha pode ser provocada porque, sob as configurações padrão, o SQL Server não permite conexões remotas. (provedor: Provedor TCP, erro: 0 – Falha em uma tentativa de conexão porque a parte conectada não respondeu corretamente após um período ou houve falha na conexão estabelecida devido a uma falha na resposta do host conectado). (Microsoft SQL Server, Erro: 10060)